# How to Bind OData $count from expanded collection in an XML view

Tags: sapui5

May be this is a basic question, but I have trouble binding the OData count in XML view.

In the following example, I want to bind the count of products from the OData model.

```xml
<List items="{/Categories}"} >  
  <ObjectListItem
    title="{CategoryName}"
    number="{path : 'Products/$count'}"
    numberUnit="Products"/>
</List>
```

Each category needs to display count of products in the respective category as in

```
/Categories(1)/Products/$count
/Categories(2)/Products/$count
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think its currently possible
- $count is an OData query option, the equivalent in ODataListBinding is length, eg Products.length I cant think of a way to bind to it

you can achieve the count in a couple of ways using a formatter

option 1 - the simplest, create a list binding which reads the total number of products, it does a synchronous call and returns only the $count

```
function productCount(oValue) {
    //return the number of products linked to Category // sync call only to get $count
    if (oValue) {
        var sPath = this.getBindingContext().getPath() + '/Products';
        var oBindings = this.getModel().bindList(sPath);
        return oBindings.getLength();
    }
};

<List items="{/Categories}"} >  
 <ObjectListItem 
    title="{CategoryName}"
    number="{path : 'CategoryName',formatter:'productCount'}"
    numberUnit="Products" 
 </ObjectListItem>
</List>
```

option 2 - use an expand and return a very small set of data, in this case only CategoryName and ProductID, the caveat here is whether you have to by pass table paging to get full list

```
function productCount(oValue) {
    //read the number of products returned
    if (oValue) {
        return oValue.length;
    }
};

<List items="{/Categories,parameters:{expand:'Products', select:'CategoryName,Products/ProductID'}}">  
 <ObjectListItem 
    title="{CategoryName}"
    number="{path : 'Products',formatter:'productCount'}"
    numberUnit="Products" 
 </ObjectListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue. Although I am not thrilled with my solution, it uses expression binding and works without the need for a separate formatter:

```
<List items="{/Categories}"} >  
  <ObjectListItem 
    title="{CategoryName}"
    number="{= ${Products}.length }"
    numberUnit="Products" />
</List>
```

Like @Jasper_07, you still need to include `Products` in the expand, but you are ignoring most of the data coming back.

Comment: Why aren't you "thrilled" with this solution? It works like a charm and is far more efficient and concise than those solutions with custom formatters and secondary queries below.

Comment: @Philipp If I recall, I wasn't thrilled because you are still getting more data coming back, but you are ignoring it. It would be better if the server never sent it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Well.. I had **exactly** the same requirement and didn't want to perform the clever solution from @jasper as it will load all Products collection from the oData service.

This was the way I solve it:

#### View

1. Use a controller
2. Give your list an ID
3. Use a function on list's [`updateFinished`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/events/updateFinished) event.

```xml
<mvc:View 
  controllerName="view.Root"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
>
  <List id="list"
    headerText="Categories"
    items="{/Categories}"
    growing="true"
    growingThreshold="4"
    growingScrollToLoad="true"
    updateFinished=".countProducts"
  >
    <ObjectListItem
      title="{description}"
      numberUnit="Products"
    />
  </List>
</mvc:View>
```

#### Controller

1. Implement `countProducts` function
2. Use jQuery to request the $count for each list item - Notice how the URL is generated concatenating model's service URL with the item's binding context
3. As jQuery uses asynchronous requests, by the time you get the first response, your `for` will be finished. So it can use [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to avoid filling just the last list item with your AJAX response

```js
countProducts: function(e){
  var m = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
  var items = this.byId("list").getItems();    
  for (var item_index = 0; item_index < items.length; item_index++) {
    var item = items[item_index];
    (function(_item) {
      $.get(
        m.sServiceUrl + _item.getBindingContextPath() + "/Categorias/$count",
        function(count) {
          _item.setNumber(count);
        }
      );
    })(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d another solution using Manifest.json, Component.js and Controller.js for similar Issue.

First, I defined the Id in App.view.xml, for example:

```
<Title id="titleId" text="" level="H2"/>
```

After, I check Manifest.json, in especial:

```
{
"sap.app": {
    "dataSources": {
        "AXXX": {
            "uri": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
```

Next, in Componente.js at init:function() I put:

```
var oDataServiceUrl = this.getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.app").dataSources["AXXX"].uri;
console.log("oDataServiceUrl = ", oDataServiceUrl);
localStorage.setItem('oDataServiceUrl', oDataServiceUrl);
```

This code read Manifest.json and get Url to oDataService called AXXX.

Finnaly, I created one function in App Controller, such as:

```
countCustomersInAXXX : function (oEvent) {

    var suffix = 'Customers/$count';
    var oDataServiceUrl = localStorage.getItem('oDataServiceUrl');
    var oDataServiceUri = oDataServiceUrl.concat(suffix);
    console.log('App.controller.js: oDataServiceUri', oDataServiceUri);

    var count = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: oDataServiceUri, async: false}).responseText;
    console.log('App.controller.js: countCustomersInAXXX:' , count);

    this.getView().byId("titleId").setText(count);
}
```

This code get the quantity of Customers and set the value in titleId.

To start this process you can user a button or one event, in my case I use this Table property:

```
updateFinished="countCustomersInAXXX"
```