# Binding to length property of OData collection in XML view

Tags: sapui5

In odata visitors navigate to clients (multiplicity 1 to 1), clients navigate to photos. 
To access the count property I do the following:

> /visitors(1)/clients/photos/$count

I have a master-detail app bound to visitors, detail view contains icon tab filter, one tab of which is bound to clients. I want to display the number of photos belonging to this client in this tab.

My code is like this:

```html
<IconTabFilter
 binding="{clients}"
 visible="{= ${CHECK_PHOTO} === 0}"
 id="iconTabBarFilter2"
 icon="sap-icon://attachment"
 tooltip="{i18n>detailIconTabBarAttachments}">
 <Text text="{= ${photos}.length}"/>
</IconTabFilter>
```

But no text is displayed. What's wrong?

This code works fine and shows the list of bound photos:

```html
<IconTabFilter
 binding="{clients}"
 visible="{= ${CHECK_PHOTO} === 0}"
 id="iconTabBarFilter2"
 icon="sap-icon://attachment"
 tooltip="{i18n>detailIconTabBarAttachments}">
 <List items="{photos}">
  <ObjectListItem 
      title="{PHOTO_ID}">
   </ObjectListItem>
 </List>
</IconTabFilter>
```

Comment: What does your {photos} return?

Comment: @Matthijs it returns a list of photo objects. I've added some code to the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAPUI5 - How to Bind Odata $count to a XML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816274/sapui5-how-to-bind-odata-count-to-a-xml-view)

Comment: Did you try **dataReceived** event of the binding? It should pass data as JS object form and you can set some JSON model property with the count.

Comment: @Matthijs when I pass photos to a formatter function, it's undefined